# Bessel’s equation of order zero , what is zero referring to?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

My textbook said xy′′ + y′ + xy = 0 is a Bessel's equation of order zero. may i ask what is the zero here referring to? is it the same as when talking about first order differential equation?

Comment: Check what a general Bessel equation looks like and then compare with $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-0^2)y=0$.

Comment: It is not; as you can see this is a second-order differential equation. The Bessel functions are just indexed by a parameter $\alpha$ and "order zero" means $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: what do you mean by  "indexed by a parameter"? specifically because this equation is equals to zero?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes but what order is the general Bessel eqn?

Comment: please dont downvote me...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan could you help me out with the above question please

Comment: @LutzLehmann could you help me out here?

Comment: Read the first sentence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function, the term "order" is there for tradition, it is not connected to the differentiation order. There are many things that can be ordered, some linearly so that one can give then a number that determines their "order".